# Does Mockito cache thenAnswer blocks?

Tags: java, lambda, mockito

I have a test class with 3 test methods. Basically what I'd like to do is have different customers being used on each test, and the permissions assigned to each customer are figured out in a common method that looks pretty much like this:

```
protected void setupCustomerPermissions(final IntegrationTestCustomer customer)
{   
    System.out.println("customer = " + customer.getName());

    when(permissionClient.createToken()).thenAnswer(invocation ->
    {
        System.out.println("customer again = " + customer.getName());

        if (customer.equals(IntegrationTestCustomer.KRISTIN())) {
            return createToken(IntegrationTestCustomer.KRISTIN());
        } else if (customer.equals(IntegrationTestCustomer.FRED())) {
            return createToken(IntegrationTestCustomer.FRED());
        } else if (customer.equals(IntegrationTestCustomer.DANIELA())) {
            return createToken(IntegrationTestCustomer.DANIELA());
        }

        throw new IllegalStateException("IntegrationTestCustomer:[" + customer.getName() + "] shouldn't have got this far");
    });
}
```

Basically, I have 3 tests: the first uses KRISTIN as a customer, the second uses FRED and the third uses KRISTIN again.

Notice the `System.out.println` calls. When the first test runs (using KRISTIN as a customer), this is what gets printed:

```
customer = KRISTIN
customer again = KRISTIN
```

So far, so good. Now comes the funny part... The second test (which uses FRED as a customer) prints **this**:

```
customer = FRED
customer again = KRISTIN
```

And then the third test, which uses KRISTIN again, prints:

```
customer = KRISTIN
customer again = FRED
```

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong here... should both `System.out.println` calls print the same customer? Does Mockito have some sort of caching in place?

Comment: Side note: you might want to listen to http://www.se-radio.net/2016/05/se-radio-episode-256-jay-fields-on-working-effectively-with-unit-tests/ ... that guy there argues that exactly that idea, of having such "test roles" like Kristin and others in your unit tests is pretty much an **antipattern** nowadays.

Comment: @IndraUprade thanks for the suggestion, but I'm not sure I get it. How could PowerMockito fix this problem?

Comment: Can you try to replace your inner `customer.getName()` with something like `invocation.getArguments()[0]` and see if it changes anything?

Comment: Do you create a new permissionClient instance for every test?

Comment: Please post the whole test, or at least the relevant parts where `customer` is being assigned.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem was cache settings on Spring security test configurations.

Comment: No need to apologize, but if you'd like to help future readers make the most of their time, _add details to both your question and your answer_ about your setup and about which configuration settings you needed to check/adjust to get your test working better.